# Distribute file copy to executors

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, amazon-emr, distcp

I have a bunch of data (on S3) that I am copying to a local HDFS (on amazon EMR). Right now I'm doing that using `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy`, but it's not clear if this distributes the file copy to the executors. There's certainly nothing showing up in the Spark History server.

Hadoop `DistCp` seems like the thing (note I'm on S3, so it's actually supposed to be `s3-dist-cp` which is built on top of `dist-cp`) except that it's a command-line tool. I'm looking for a way to invoke this from a Scala script (aka, Java).

Any ideas / leads?

Comment: Look at unit tests of Hadoop tools on how to use it programmatically, https://github.com/apache/hadoop/tree/3e3963b035911703c61e6d9a2939eb894da5644c/hadoop-tools/hadoop-distcp/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/tools

Answer (score 1):

[cloudcp](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/cloud-integration/blob/master/spark-cloud-integration/src/main/scala/com/hortonworks/spark/cloud/applications/CloudCp.scala) is an example of using Spark to do the copy; the list of files is turned into an RDD, each row == a copy. That design is optimised for upload from HDFS, as it tries to schedule the upload close to the files in HDFS.

For download, you want to

- use listFiles(path, recursive) for maximum performance in listing an object store.
- randomise the list of source files so that you don't get throttled by AWS
- randomise the placement across the HDFS cluster so that the blocks end up scattered evenly round the cluster

Comment: Neat, I'll give this a go.

Comment: nothing to hand: it's just a spark job on the CLI after all